# How to Remove Bullets from an Alphabetically Sorted List

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem, sorting, bullets

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\sortitem}[2][\relax]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \ifx#1\relax
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#2}% Add entry sortlabel (no optional argument)
  \else
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#1}% Add entry sortlabel (optional argument)
  \fi%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}% Add entry description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{sortlabel}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*} % Global noindent

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{sortedlist} %[label={}]
  \sortitem[ZGROUP]{\textbf{ZGROUP}}
  \sortitem[DGROUP]{\textbf{DGROUP}}
  \sortitem[BGROUP]{\textbf{BGROUP}}
  \sortitem[CGROUP]{\textbf{CGROUP}}
  \sortitem[AGROUP]{\textbf{AGROUP}}
\end{sortedlist}
\end{document}
```

which produces the sorted list:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I remove the default bullets from this sorted list? Also, if there is a simpler way of producing this list, please advise.

*Remark:* I have tried using `[label={}]`, which works for `itemize`, but not for the customized `sortedlist`. Nevertheless, the command `\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*} does work for preventing indentation of the items.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `sortedlist` environment is not a custom list, but simply contains an  `itemize` environment inside it, you need to add the `[label={}]` inside the `sortedlist` definition. And because you probably don't want a global definition for `itemize` I've commented out that line and added the `leftmargin=*` inside the definition too.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\sortitem}[2][\relax]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \ifx#1\relax
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#2}% Add entry sortlabel (no optional argument)
  \else
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#1}% Add entry sortlabel (optional argument)
  \fi%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}% Add entry description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{sortlabel}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}[label={},leftmargin=*]
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}

%\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*} % Global noindent

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem[ZGROUP]{\textbf{ZGROUP}}
  \sortitem[DGROUP]{\textbf{DGROUP}}
  \sortitem[BGROUP]{\textbf{BGROUP}}
  \sortitem[CGROUP]{\textbf{CGROUP}}
  \sortitem[AGROUP]{\textbf{AGROUP}}
\end{sortedlist}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you for this answer and the information you provided.